# Flutter Google Sign-In PlatformException (sign_in_failed, ApiException: 10) Error

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-signin

'm encountering a PlatformException when trying to implement Google Sign-In in my Flutter app. The error occurs during the sign-in process, throwing an ApiException: 10. Here's the error log:

```
E/flutter (12293): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)
E/flutter (12293): #0      GoogleSignInApi.signIn (package:google_sign_in_android/src/messages.g.dart:221)
E/flutter (12293): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12293): #1      GoogleSignInAndroid._signInUserDataFromChannelData (package:google_sign_in_android/google_sign_in_android.dart:111)
E/flutter (12293): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12293): #2      GoogleSignIn._callMethod (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:278)
E/flutter (12293): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (12293): #3      GoogleSignIn.signIn.isCanceled (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:431)
E/flutter (12293): <asynchronous suspension>
```

What I've Tried:

1. I have published this app for the last 5 years, the same package and signature, and perfectly working with old app,(codebase : Kotlin)
2. No issue when app gmail login in debug mode,

2.Verified that the Google Sign-In API is enabled in the Google Cloud Console.
Checked that the OAuth 2.0 client IDs match my app's package name and SHA-1 certificate fingerprint.

3.Confirmed the AndroidManifest.xml contains the correct metadata for Google Sign-In.

4.Ensured that error handling is implemented correctly in the Dart code for Google Sign-In.

How can I resolve the PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null) error in Flutter when implementing Google Sign-In? Are there specific configurations in the Google Cloud Console or the Flutter project setup that I might be missing?

Any guidance or suggestions on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.?